# Lego China Cabinet

Tags: design

I'm building a Lego china cabinet and I'm looking for some nice pieces to put in it. (Fancy dishes, table settings etc). Here's a picture of what I have so far:
[image]

Here's some pieces I've identified in my want list so far:

- [dragon bowl](https://www.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=34172pb02&C=0)
- [Minifigure, Utensil Bowl with Gold Rim and Stripe Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=34172pb03&C=0)
- [Minifigure, Utensil Bowl with White Rim and Waves Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=34172pb01&C=0)
- [Glass for Window 1 x 2 x 2 Flat Front with Ornamented Window Arch Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=60601pb013&C=12)
- [Minifigure, Utensil Sun Disk](https://www.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=x276&C=21)
- And of course the usual goblets and wine bottles.

Can you suggest any other nice pieces that would go well in this build?

Comment: How about tea cups with saucer? That’s a recent mould that should be easy to get

Answer (score 2):

There are some nice tea bowls in the Tranquil Garden Set. You could also appropriate some pieces as figurines, such as the famous frog in a pretty color, or some of the tiny flower combinations. My grandmother used to keep such china figurines in her cabinet.

Answer (score 0):

You could go macabre, and source a pirate skull, or a ninjago villain such as this snake head

http://76.my/Malaysia/lego-ninjago-snake-villain-spitta-minifigure-newl-yesbrick-1307-08-yesbrick@1.jpg

Comment: Make it a gruesome trophy case huh?  I would but this is a christmas gift so I think I'm looking for a more traditional look